# How to get the authorization code in DocuSign?

Tags: nuxt.js, docusignapi

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f&state=a39fh23hnf23&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback/
```

How to use this and get the response?, I want to integrate it to my Nuxt.js apps.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

We have a node example here https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node.
For OAuth authentication guide you can check here https://developers.docusign.com/docs/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/